# Can I change the behaviour of the Insert Table command in Word 2007?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

In Word 2007, the "Insert" ribbon tab has a "Tables" group with a single drop-down button (labelled "Table").

The drop-down contains various menu items such as "Insert Table...", "Draw Table", etc. However, at the top of the drop-down there's a 10x8 grid that you can use to quickly choose the size of your new table using the mouse. (First question: what the heck is this thing called?!!).

I'd like to override the default behaviour, so that when the user "draws" a table using the widget mentioned above, I can change the paragraph style used within the table (and perhaps do some other clean-up).

I know how to override the "Insert Table..." command, but I can't figure out how to override the behaviour of the "widget". Can it be done?

Comment: From what I know you can't. You might want to change the Table Normal style though, so that any newly inserted table gets your style.

Comment: @0xA3: I have made some changes to Table Normal, but the problem is that a table style does not allow you set the paragraph style. You can change aspects of the formatting, but it doesn't play well with styles. (See http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/styles/custom-table-styles-2002-2003.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you read on (because this will be long) I want to say that I did not solve this problem. However, in my attempts to solve -- and then work around -- this issue, I discovered quite a few things, which I am recording here in the hope that they will help someone else find the solution.

While trying to determine what controls the 10x8 grid that one can use to insert a table, I discovered a macro listed within the Word commands named "TableInsertGeneral".

[image: TableInsertGeneral listed in Word Macros dialog box]

This macro, according to Suzanne S. Barnhill, will restore the grid if this feature ceases to function in earlier versions of Word ([Insert Table Drop Down Missing](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx)). The macro, as it exists in Word 2007/2010, cannot be executed from the macro dialog box Run button. Double-clicking on the command dismisses the dialog box, but does not overtly do anything else. I additionally tried to intercept its function, by creating a VBA sub named TableInsertGeneral, but code I placed into this sub did not appear to be executed when I accessed the grid. However, based on my research I believe the TableInsertGeneral macro does have some connection to displaying the 10x8 grid.

I also attempted to work around the problem by altering the Tables Gallery in the Word Ribbon. Because I could not directly access any code that controlled the grid, I attempted to hide the Tables Gallery and then replace it with a rebuilt gallery that excluded the grid function (thus allowing the paragraph style and other changes to work globally).

First I downloaded some tools:

- The Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office (for editing the Ribbon: [Office Custom UI Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx))
- Office 2007 Control IDs (for identifying the names of various Ribbon parts: [Office 2007 Control IDs in Excel worksheet](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=3582))
- The Office 2007 Icons Gallery (for accessing the internal icons within Word to place in the rebuilt Ribbon: [Word 2007 Icons Gallery](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11675))

Using the Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office (which allows one to edit the customui.xml file inside a Word 2007 document or template without needing to create folder structures or maintain relationships between xml files) I opened a template and saved this code within the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon>
  <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabInsert">
      <group idMso="GroupInsertTables" visible="false" />
      <group id="CustomGroupInsertTables" label="Tables" insertBeforeMso="GroupInsertIllustrations">
       <gallery id="CustomTableInsertGallery"
        label="Table"
        imageMso="TableInsertGallery" 
        size="large"
        columns="1" 
        rows="4"
        screentip="Table"
        supertip="Insert or draw a table into the document."
        keytip="T" 
        onAction="RibbonControl.galleryOnAction" >
        <item id="GridMessage" label="Draw Table Via Grid Has Been Removed" imageMso="TablesGallery" 
         supertip="Provides information on why this template has different Ribbon controls."/>  
        <button idMso="TableInsertDialogWord" />
        <button idMso="ConvertTextToTable" />
        <button idMso="TableExcelSpreadsheetInsert" />
       </gallery>
     </group>
    </tab>
  </tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

This successfully hid the original Tables gallery and replaced it with some of the functionality of the original Tables gallery. The 10x8 grid was gone, but I was unable to restore the Draw Table toggle button and Quick Tables gallery. As far as I can tell, the XML schema does not allow for embedding either of these (which exist in the out-of-the-box version of Word 2007) into an existing gallery. Because I do not like removing functionality (even for this partial solution, which I did not think would be employed), I added a button tied to a message box as the first item in the rebuilt gallery:

[image: Rebuilt Tables Gallery]

The code for connecting the new "Draw Table Via Grid Has Been Removed" button was placed in a module named RibbonControl:

```
Sub GalleryOnAction(Control As IRibbonControl, selectedID As String, selectedIndex As Integer)

If Documents.Count = 0 Then
 MsgBox "This control is disabled when there is no active document."
 Exit Sub
End If

Select Case Control.id
  Case "CustomTableInsertGallery"
    Select Case selectedIndex
      Case 0
        MsgBox "Explain changes to Ribbon interface here."
      Case Else
        'Do Nothing
    End Select 
End Select
End Sub
```

I do not expect anyone to use this partial solution, however, if a means for restoring the two missing controls could be achieved, this might be a good workaround. By the way, I adapted most of this from Greg Maxey's Web site:

[Customizing the Ribbon](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Customize_Ribbon.htm)

If you read this far, thanks! And I wish you more success with your own attempts.

Comment: I'm going to accept this excellent, fullsome answer on the basis that the summary is "no" :-)